# Nothing shows up while calling a method

Tags: android, android-studio

I was developing an exam score calculator app.
When I want to call AD methods,advertisements don't show up.

Calculation process happens in OnCreate method:

```
public class resultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String responseId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        /*Calculation...*/}
```

and other voids like:

```
public void requestAd() {
/*AD RQUESTING PROCESS...*/
}
```

and

```
 public void showAd() {
/*AD SHOWING PROCESS...*/
}
```

AD team gave me this code to call the method and it works well:

```
requestButton.setOnClickListener(v -> requestAd());
 showButton.setOnClickListener(v -> showAd());
```

But the Problem is I don't have buttons to call them so I tried this:

```
public class resultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String responseId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        requestAd();
        showAd();

        /*Calculation...*/}
```

But when the activity starts ads don't show up!
The whole question is I want this methods to be called while this activity starts.
thank you.

Comment: try to to put these in onStart()/onResume().

Comment: Nothing happened

Comment: you should put showAd() inside your requestAd(), Just check when ad is loaded then call showAd()
You have to upload complete code for more help ! Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing special in complete code .

Comment: As I said, the problem is I don't how to recall a method like requestAd(); in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

Try building up the release version APK and test on it. Maybe your Ad-provider have some restrictions in debug version?

Comment: I tested but there is no results!

Answer (score 0):

I made another class and moved request `Ad` and `showAd` there. Then, I made an object and called the method through object.
I have to mention that I changed a minor thing in `requestAd` but the main job was done by the object.
Thank You All.